# Kubernetes - Liveness httpGet probe closes the connection before reading the entire body

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, livenessprobe

Below is the current configuration of my liveness probe:

```yaml
  livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /connectors
        port: 8083
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
      periodSeconds: 60
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
      timeoutSeconds: 15
```

Kubelet pings the endpoint and gets 200. However, the probe closes the connection before reading the entire body. This is causing the server to have broken pipes.

Is there a way to ensure that kubelet reads the entire body before closing the connection?

Note: My probe doesn't have to rely on the response body.

Comment: Have your application provide an endpoint specifically for healthchecks that delivers a minimal body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`httpGet` probe has hardcoded [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5323d9213a8c68f9279b3b73fc65c663febcfe16/pkg/probe/http/http.go#L98) to read only a 10 KB response. Anything beyond that will not be read. So, it is impossible to read the complete response from the liveness probe.

Alternate solution: Fixing the health check endpoint to deliver a minimal body is an alternate solution.